# Spring 5 constantly losing connection to the DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hikaricp

I know this question was asked a lot and there is ton of articles about it, but none of the solutions seem to work for me, I'm new to Spring so maybe I'm missing something.

I'm using spring 5.0.6 , spring boot 2.0.0, with hibernate, mysql and Hikari pool.
My app connects successfully and performing succesfull query and then losing connection. Here's related application config:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://server/db?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 20000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

I've also tried setting config specific to hikari, still no luck.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=1
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If so which version?

Comment: Because I never had any issues with Spring, I would purpose to look inside `HikariCP`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've edited the question, spring boot 2.0.2

Comment: Other thing, it seems to be useless to have two connection checking.

Comment: You don't need the validation/test query. It is JDBC 4 which has better ways of validating. You should specify the hikari settings for testing while idle etc. those aren't in the global namespace anymore.

Comment: @Zorglube I agree, but unfortunately none of those work for me.

Comment: @M.Deinum As you can see i setup hikari settings, but it still didn't work.

Comment: See https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4

Comment: You have only set a few Hikari properties you haven't set the properties that actually matter. Also what type of connection loss are you experiencing?

Comment: How did you solve this? We have the same issue with MS SQL.